# Why Hibernate change DateTime stored in DataBase?

Tags: java, hibernate, datetime, java-time

I have issue that I can not resolve. I'm using **Hibernate 4.3.9 Final** and **hibernate-java8 5.0.0.CR3** to work with **jdk8 time**. In my mapping file I have "actualDate" with type **org.hibernate.type.InstantType**. I stored it in database with DateTime format. When I create this java.time.Instant I'm using ZoneId passing to my object. After creating Instant I save it into database end everything is ok, but when I read from the database Hibernate change this time. For example I have ZoneId "Warsaw/Poland" and I store in database value "2015-07-31 09:10:00" I see this value in database. But when I read it changes to "2015-07-31 07:10:00". I mean when I read this value and assign it in my code it changes. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Can you post your entity class code and you persistence.xml?

Comment: Is the machine you're reading it on in a TZ two hours different?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And how exactly is `actualDate` defined in the database? (Show us the `create table` statement)

Comment: actualDate is just DateTime. I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

"2015-07-31 07:10:00" is the UTC conversion of "2015-07-31 09:10:00" because Warsaw/Poland is +2 Hours from UTC.

If you have a DateTimeZone you could use a call that would look like this

```
public static DateTime convertUTCToDateTimeZone(DateTime dateTime, DateTimeZone timeZone) {
    return dateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).toDateTime(timeZone);
}
```

This has worked for me but of course I do not know anything about your system.

Good luck.

Comment: The problem is that "2015-07-31 07:10:00"  is already in UTC. I mean when I create this date it is in UTC. So conversion to UTC is running two times.